# sending image file and body data with axios post

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I was wondering how to send an image and other data to my node server using axios in react.This is the code I have and I can either send the formData or the data currently. Help on how to get them both to the controller on my server would be appreciated.

### client side

```
const [file,setFile] = useState('')
const [productName,setProduct] = useState('')

const onSubmit = (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file',file)
  fd.append('product',productName)    
   axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload/product',fd,{
     headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
       }
   })
```

### server side

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const productStorage =  multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './client/public/upload',
    filename : (req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage : productStorage,
    limits:{fileSize:1000000},
}).single("file")

app.post('/upload/product',(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.body.product)  // undefined ??? <-- my problem 
upload(req,res,err=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('upload failed')
    }else{
        console.log('upload success')
    }
})
})
```

i can receive the file but i cant receive the product name string . the console shows undefined.

Comment: try cosole.log(req.body) to see what is being received  in the body actually.

Comment: its just showing "{}"